# Vue.js materialize jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, materialize

cant seem to get modal and datepicker in Vue.js. I tried simply what is found in the documentation and I tried already many solutions but I cant get them to work.  Is there any proper way of adding materialize components to vue.js that requires jquery initialization.

tried inserting this into my template

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

then I included a js file in my index.html

```
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    today: 'Today',
    clear: 'Clear',
    close: 'Ok',
    closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
  });
```

Comment: Your element won't exist until the Vue component is rendered, so putting it in `index.html` won't actually affect anything. Your initialization JS should go in the Vue component's `mounted()` function, most likely.

Comment: really helped! thank you

Comment: dont forget to destroy before unmount. Sometimes htmls created by jquery plugins inside body element stacking after many times created.

Comment: how do you do that? I am just beginning to understand vue.js